# LogicException: Missing default data in Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DataCollector\MessageDataCollector

Tags: symfony, phpunit, profiler, swiftmailer

Getting this exception in Symfony 2.5.5 with Swiftmailer 5.3.0.  I'm following the [cookbook example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html) exactly.  The error is thrown when calling `MessageDataCollector#getMessages()`:

```
// Check that an e-mail was sent
$this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

$collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
$message = $collectedMessages[0];
```

The message count assertion is also failing with a value of zero.

As far as I can tell the collector is failing to do any actual collecting in the action.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you add the whole function where you've this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem after I applied [**kriswallsmith's test optimization trick**](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/27979797907/get-fast-an-easy-symfony2-phpunit-optimization). I could see the result of the mail sending in the web profiler when running the development version, but couldn't get the data in the testing environment.

After applying Kris' trick I noticed that the **swiftmailer.mailer.default.plugin.messagelogger** service was not registered with the container during the test, so the **collect() method** of the **MessageDataCollector class** did not log the data for the mail sending. This is why it wasn't possible to retrieve information from the swiftmailer collector.

The solution is either not to overrride the **initializeContainer()** method in **AppKernel.php** or to override it, but making sure **messagelogger** service is available for test cases that send mails.

Comment: Wow. Yes. That is *exactly* what was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: see my answer below why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had **multiple mailers** in the `config.yml` file and the same problem was due to a **missing parameter** in the `getMessages()` call.

My `config.yml` file:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default_mailer
    mailers:
        default_mailer:
          # some configuration
        another_mailer:
          # some configuration
```

The correct call was:

```
$mailCollector = $this->client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
$collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages('default_mailer'); // please note the 'default_mailer' argument
$messagesCount = $mailCollector->getMessageCount('default_mailer')
```

Comment: _This_ is exactly what my problem was! I had to do the same with `getMessageCount()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

@codeBetyar is right - problem occurs when `swiftmailer.mailer.default.plugin.messagelogger` is not registered in container.

But instead of getting rid of the optimization trick - you just need to update swiftmailer configuration for test environment

```
swiftmailer:
    logging: true
```

The thing is `logging` config value by default equals to `kernel.debug` (https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L121) which (thanks to the trick) is `true` for the first test request, and `false` - for all following requests.

Above config forces logger being registered.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that apparently if there are no messages to retrieve (or perhaps no swiftmailer instantiation in the code being tested?), the call to getMessages() returns this obtuse error. So I bypassed the problem by testing for getMessageCount() first.