# Testing Symfony2 emails with Behat 3

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, behat

I followed the [Behat 2.5 docs](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_the_profiler_with_minkbundle.html) to test mails. After a few tweaks to match Behat 3 I have ended with the following code (I have removed non-relevant parts):

```php
public function getSymfonyProfile()
{
    $driver = $this->mink->getSession()->getDriver();

    if (!$driver instanceof KernelDriver) {
        // Throw exception
    }

    $profile = $driver->getClient()->getProfile();
    if (false === $profile) {
        // Throw exception
    }

    return $profile;
}

/**
 * @Then I should get an email with subject :subject on :email
 */
public function iShouldGetAnEmail($subject, $email)
{
    $profile   = $this->getSymfonyProfile();
    $collector = $profile->getCollector('swiftmailer');

    foreach ($collector->getMessages() as $message) {
        // Assert email
    }

    // Throw an error if something went wrong
}
```

When I run this test, **it throws the following error**:

```
exception 'LogicException' with message 'Missing default data in Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DataCollector\MessageDataCollector' in vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/DataCollector/MessageDataCollector.php:93
Stack trace:
    #0 vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/DataCollector/MessageDataCollector.php(122): Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DataCollector\MessageDataCollector->getMailerData('default')
    #1 features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php(107): Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DataCollector\MessageDataCollector->getMessages()
```

My profiler is configured as follows:

```yaml
# app/config/config_test.yml
framework:
    test: ~
    profiler:
        enabled: true
        collect: true
```

It seems that the `Profile` is correctly loaded and the `MessageDataCollector` from `Swiftmailer` does exist, but it is not doing its work as expected. **Any clue to solve this?**

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270493/logicexception-missing-default-data-in-symfony-bundle-swiftmailerbundle-datacol

Comment: No, that's a different issue, I didn't touch `AppKernel.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the issue you have has been fixed as I do not have this anymore (I'm using Behat v3.0.15, BrowserKit driver 1.3.* and Symfony v2.6.6).

I managed to reproduce your error but only when I forgot to enable profiler data collecting:

```
profiler:
    collect: false
```

Once this problem solved (the configuration you provided solving the problem for me) I managed to check emails in my Behat tests.
Two solutions for this:

### Solution #1: Intercepting redirects globally

If it does not break all your other tests you can do so by configuring your web profiler as follows:

```
web_profiler:
    intercept_redirects: true
```

### Solution #2: Preventing client to follow redirections temporarily

For my part, intercepting redirections globally in the configuration broke most of my other functional tests. I therefore use this method instead.

As preventing redirections allows mainly to check data in the data collectors I decided to use a tag `@collect` on each scenario requiring redirect interception. I then used `@BeforeScenario` and `@AfterScenario` to enable this behaviour only for those scenarios:

```
/**
 * Follow client redirection once
 *
 * @Then /^(?:|I )follow the redirection$/
 */
public function followRedirect()
{
    $this->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirect();
}

/**
 * Restore the automatic following of redirections
 *
 * @param BeforeScenarioScope $scope
 *
 * @BeforeScenario @collect
 */
public static function disableFollowRedirects(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
    $context = $scope->getEnvironment()->getContext(get_class());
    $context->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirects(false);
}

/**
 * Restore the automatic following of redirections
 *
 * @param AfterScenarioScope $scope
 *
 * @AfterScenario @collect
 */
public static function restoreFollowRedirects(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
{
    $context = $scope->getEnvironment()->getContext(get_class());
    $context->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirects(true);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, latest versions solve the exception I was getting but still I needed to stop following redirections to access the collected messages (redirections seem to clean the collector). In my case, instead of disabling redirections for the scenario, I defined a "Then I stop following redirections" step; but it is the same idea as yours. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

It's not the answer your are looking for, but I'm pretty sure it will suits your needs (perhaps more).
If I can suggest, try using Mailcatcher with this bundle: https://packagist.org/packages/alexandresalome/mailcatcher
You'll be able to easily tests if emails are sent, what's their subject, follow a link in the body, and so on...
Many steps are included with this bundle.

Comment: This bundle is not yet compatible with behat 3

Comment: take a look at this blog http://www.elao.com/fr/blog/tester-lenvoi-de-mail-avec-behat-dans-une-application-symfony2 maybe you find a solution.

Comment: +1 for using mailcatcher. it will do end to end testing and you can be sure that the email sending is tested properly. using symfony profiler is more of a hack. if there is some edge case and a bug in swiftmailer or profiler, you might not catch it.

Comment: @greg0ire This bundle is now compatible with behat 3 (since last year I think). https://github.com/alexandresalome/mailcatcher/pull/9

Comment: lol these commit messages are the worst! Anyway, have my upvote

Comment: This is genius! <3 Works like a charm :-)